# Check convergence of the series:

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Check convergence of the series:

$\sum a_n=\sum \dfrac{n^4}{e^{n^2}}$ .

I know that the rate of convergence of polynomial function is less than that of a exponential function.Hence $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=0$

How to check its convergence?Please help.

Comment: You could use $e^x > \frac{1}{3!} x^3$

Comment: Here the root test is quite straightforward.

Comment: Your series can be expressed in terms of derivatives of [$\theta$ functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\dfrac{(n^{\frac{1}{n}})^4}{e^n}\to 0<1$ as $n\to \infty$;

By Cauchy's root test series converges

Answer (score 2):

By proof we have $\frac{x^{a}}{e^{bx}} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ for all $a,b > 0$; applying this result gives
$$
\frac{n^{4}}{e^{n^{2}}} \leq \frac{n^{4}}{n^{6}} = n^{-2}
$$
for large $n$.
By comparison test we have got the desired convergence.

Answer (score 2):

What about the series-integral test? We have:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^4}{e^{n^2}}\approx \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^4 e^{-x^2}\, dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty} z^{3/2}e^{-z}\,dz = \frac{\Gamma(5/2)}{2}=\frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{8}.$$